# How to generate unique small integer from a larger integer

Tags: php, unique

I want to generate a unique small integer between 1 and 3 from a larger one coming from an id. E.g:

```
id: 348593 ----> generated: 2

id: 98762  ----> generated: 3 

id: 12     ----> generated: 1
```

I did it using module for two numbers (1 and 2):

```php
$id = 43784643;
$module = $id % 2; // 0 if even, 1 if odd

$generated = $module + 1;
```

How would you do this, considering that the small number must be always the same for the same id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already have a good solution: modulus.

```
$generated = ($id % 3) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your solution, but you need to use `3` instead of `2`.

I would also skip the creation of a pointless variable, but otherwise I would say that is a solid solution.

If there is an issue, could you elaborate on the problem.

```
$test = array(
        123456789,987654321,2222,111111,
        5555555,63243514513,7,43,222,
        65462,9191910);

foreach($test as $k=>$v) {
    echo '['.$v.'] ['.(($v % 3) +1).']';
}
```

Result:

```
[123456789] [1]
[987654321] [1]
[2222] [3]
[111111] [1]
[5555555] [3]
[63243514513] [2]
[7] [2]
[43] [2]
[222] [1]
[65462] [3]
[9191910] [1]
```